# What does it mean if zero bytes of data are received from a callback function of curl?

Tags: c, curl

I am getting zero bytes as data from the callback function of curl. What does it actually mean?

```
struct MemoryStruct
{
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    char *ptr = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    mem->memory = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;
    return realsize;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct MemoryStruct chunk;

    chunk.memory = NULL;
    chunk.size = 0;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://emaple.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &chunk);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d bytes retrieved %p \n", (int)chunk.size, chunk.memory);
        }
        …
    }
    …
}
```

If I am not wrong, the connection to the website is successful.  What does zero bytes data received mean here?

Comment: I _infer_ that you are _not_ getting an error back. Otherwise, you'd be talking about the `fprintf(stderr,...);` error message you got from `curl_easy_strerror`. So, I assume that, when the call returned, `chunk.size` was zero. To be sure, during debugging, maybe you should print _both_ messages [regardless of the value of `res`]. But, I'd add some debug `printf` to `WriteMemoryCallback` so you can see: (1) That it was, indeed, called. (2) What values it's trying to add to your memory struct. I'd have it print _all_ values that it deals with (inc. `mem->memory` and `mem->size`, `realsize`)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded, compiled, and ran your program.

The problem is that you do:

```
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

*before* any of the `curl_easy_setopt` calls.

You have to do `curl_easy_perform` *after* the `curl_easy_setopt` calls.

*Side note:* `emaple.com` was not resolvable. So, I tried `www.google.com` instead and got back (e.g.) 49741 bytes.

---

**UPDATE:**

> can you show me the code, I am still getting same thing

Sure.

In order illustrate the differences, I used preprocessor conditionals to show the differences in your/old code vs. my/new code:

```
#if 0
// old code ...
#else
// new code ...
#endif

#if 1
// new code ...
#endif
```

And, I added `argv` processing in `main`, so it will default to `https://www.google.com`, but you can invoke with (e.g.):

```
./myprogram https://www.cnn.com
```

Anyway, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *) userp;

    char *ptr = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    mem->memory = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}

#if 0
int
main(void)
#else
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
#endif
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
#if 1
    int code = 2;
#endif

#if 1
    --argc;
    ++argv;
#endif

    chunk.memory = NULL;
    chunk.size = 0;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        // NOTE/BUG: this is what actually does the work -- at this point,
        // _no_ options have been set -- this is the _primary_ bug
#if 0
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
#endif

        // NOTE/BUG: emaple.com was _not_ accessible/existing for me
#if 0
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://emaple.com");
#else
        char *url;

        // allow command line override of URL
        if (argc > 0)
            url = *argv;

        // use default URL
        else
            url = "https://www.google.com";

        printf("URL: %s\n",url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
#endif

        // NOTES:
        // (1) the doc for CURLOPT_HTTPGET says that it "overrides" previous
        //     access methods!?!?
        // (2) so, CURLOPT_HTTPGET _may_ nullify the use of CURLOPT_POST
        // (3) it works as is, but it's something to check on later
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);

        /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &chunk);

        // NOTE/FIX: this is where this statement should actually go
#if 1
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
#endif

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
            code = 1;
        }
        else {
            printf("%d bytes retrieved %p \n", (int) chunk.size, chunk.memory);
            code = 0;
        }
    }

#if 1
    return code;
#endif
}
```

Comment: can you show me the code, I am still getting same thing